# Calculate the ratio of area of different colors in an image

Tags: python, image, rgb

I am trying to calculate the proportion of colors in an image and return this as a ratio. I have lots of images of "logs" which are vertical sequences of colors and I would like to know the difference of the total area of 1 color, compared to the other, and a ratio of the 1 color relative to the whole image.

As an example, in the image below, if I calculate the total area occupied by the blue color and compare it to the whole area (blue and brown combined, I get the ratio = 69.14. (I got that value by summing up the area of all the blue rectangles and dividing it by the summed area of all the blue and brown rectangles)

*note, the colors will not always be the ones below, and I would like to be able to use more than two colors if that is a possibility (and perhaps just give the RGB code of the color I'm focused on and want the ratio of that color to the whole of).

Note I have LOTS of images I would have to run this one so it would be helpful to loop over all images in a folder if that is a possibility.

I pieced together to code below from a couple of examples, but I am confused on a few things. One, I don't necessarily want to convert the image to binary unless I have to, and two, it looks like I'm calculating the number of white pixels rather than black. Not sure where I am going wrong.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# load image
image = cv2.imread('/Users/Me/Desktop/logtest.png',0)

# plot the binary image
imgplot = plt.imshow(image, "gray")
plt.show()

#Calculate percent of pixels that are black
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(image,0,230, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
height, width = image.shape

print ("Height and Width : ",height, width)
size = image.size

print ("Total number of pixels in the image is =", size)

ChosenPix = cv2.countNonZero(image)
print("Total number of black pixels =", count)

Ratio = (ChosenPix/size)*100
print("Ratio of black to total is =", Ratio)
```

[image]

Comment: @Prune edited based on your comments.

Comment: Good -- you're close to the [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) we expect.  What output do you get, and what did you expect?  Is `logtest.png` also the file you posted?  You refer to black & white pixels, but your posting has brown and turquoise.

Comment: I have also nominated question for re-opening. You may not be aware, but your current image contains 6 unique colours, not the 2 you suggest. Please add a further example - maybe one with 3 colours. Also, please define **LOTS**, is that 137 or 2million? Also, please state your OS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made a few sample images like this:

[image] [image] [image]

Then I used a glob to select all files named `log*png` and processed each one. That consisted of counting the unique colours in the image and iterating over those colours to count how many pixels matched each unique colour:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import glob

def processLog(filename):
    print(f"Processing log: {filename}")
    # Open this image and make a Numpy version for easy processing
    im   = Image.open(filename).convert('RGBA').convert('RGB')
    imnp = np.array(im)
    h, w = imnp.shape[:2]

    # Get list of unique colours...
    # Arrange all pixels into a tall column of 3 RGB values and find unique rows (colours)
    colours, counts = np.unique(imnp.reshape(-1,3), axis=0, return_counts=1)

    # Iterate through unique colours
    for index, colour in enumerate(colours):
        count = counts[index]
        proportion = (100 * count) / (h * w)
        print(f"   Colour: {colour}, count: {count}, proportion: {proportion:.2f}%")

# Iterate over all images called "log*png" in current directory
for filename in glob.glob('log*png'):
    processLog(filename)
```

**Output**

```
Processing log: log2.png
   Colour: [  0 255 255], count: 800, proportion: 5.00%
   Colour: [255   0 255], count: 6400, proportion: 40.00%
   Colour: [255 255   0], count: 8800, proportion: 55.00%
Processing log: log1.png
   Colour: [  0 255   0], count: 6400, proportion: 36.36%
   Colour: [255   0   0], count: 11200, proportion: 63.64%
Processing log: log9.png
   Colour: [ 83 195 187], count: 16160, proportion: 67.33%
   Colour: [ 87 190 179], count: 80, proportion: 0.33%
   Colour: [ 88 184 171], count: 80, proportion: 0.33%
   Colour: [ 89 180 165], count: 80, proportion: 0.33%
   Colour: [ 94 175 158], count: 80, proportion: 0.33%
   Colour: [ 96 164 143], count: 80, proportion: 0.33%
   Colour: [107 146 116], count: 80, proportion: 0.33%
   Colour: [120 114  71], count: 80, proportion: 0.33%
   Colour: [124  99  50], count: 80, proportion: 0.33%
   Colour: [126  88  35], count: 7120, proportion: 29.67%
   Colour: [126  90  37], count: 80, proportion: 0.33%
```

---

Of course, if you don't want to write any Python, you can just iterate through the files in a `bash` loop and use **ImageMagick** to extract the total number of pixels and the number of pixels of each colour for you. **ImageMagick** is installed on most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows:

```
for f in log*png; do magick "$f" -format "%f: %[fx:w*h]\n"  -write info: -format %c histogram:info: ; done
```

**Output**

```
log1.png: 17600
      6400: (  0,255,  0) #00FF00 lime
     11200: (255,  0,  0) #FF0000 red
log2.png: 16000
       800: (  0,255,255) #00FFFF cyan
      6400: (255,  0,255) #FF00FF magenta
      8800: (255,255,  0) #FFFF00 yellow
log9.png: 24000
     16160: ( 83,195,187,255) #53C3BBFF srgba(83,195,187,1)
        80: ( 87,190,179,255) #57BEB3FF srgba(87,190,179,1)
        80: ( 88,184,171,251) #58B8ABFB srgba(88,184,171,0.984314)
        80: ( 89,180,165,255) #59B4A5FF srgba(89,180,165,1)
        80: ( 94,175,158,246) #5EAF9EF6 srgba(94,175,158,0.964706)
        80: ( 96,164,143,255) #60A48FFF srgba(96,164,143,1)
        80: (107,146,116,246) #6B9274F6 srgba(107,146,116,0.964706)
        80: (120,114, 71,246) #787247F6 srgba(120,114,71,0.964706)
        80: (124, 99, 50,255) #7C6332FF srgba(124,99,50,1)
      7120: (126, 88, 35,255) #7E5823FF srgba(126,88,35,1)
        80: (126, 90, 37,250) #7E5A25FA srgba(126,90,37,0.980392)
```

Comment: wow that's excellent! I was banging my head against the wall to try and figure something out and this works brilliantly!